# Laravel - how to redirect users to previous page, with hash from previous page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

When users login, I'd like them to be redirected to the page they were on before, with the same hash that they had from that page.

E.g. if they were on `x.com/x#abc` and log in, they should be redirected back to     `x.com/x#abc`

I'm using AJAX successfully to store the hash value upon login, to the Session:

```
Session::put('login_hash', $_POST['hash']);
```

I'm then trying to adjust the code in `RedirectsUsers.php` to append this hash value, however, this doesn't work as the `Session::get('login_hash')` is always blank.

I've checked through other views etc and see that `Session::get('login_hash')` is actually filled correctly, it's just that `RedirectsUsers.php` can't seem to access this value, so after logging in, the user just goes to `x.com/x` rather than `x.com/x#abc`

Not sure if "Use Session" is the right thing to include, given that this RedirectsUsers file is in a vendor folder?

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm on **Laravel 5.6.**

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;
use Input, Redirect, URL;
use Session;

trait RedirectsUsers
{
    /**
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (\Auth::user()->user_type=='admin') {
            $suffix = !empty(Session::get('login_hash')) ? '#' . Session::get('login_hash') : '';
            return '/admin/home' . $suffix;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting logged in using ajax?

Comment: @linktoahref no it's just via a standard PHP POST

Comment: where exactly is the ajax being fired?

Comment: As the hash is usually never transferred to the server, you can't access it there. Or do you have some JS code in place that reads the hash and places it into a input field?

Comment: @linktoahref AJAX is being fired upon the login page being loaded. I can see by testing on other URLs that the Session variable is being stored correctly

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$suffix = '#'.Session::get('login_hash');
return '/admin/home/' . $suffix;
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about this? To me, it looks pretty like the code in the question